# register_post_status and show_in_admin_all_list

Tags: post-status

I have a custom post status which should be public visible but not displayed in the "all" list of the edit screen.

This is how I register the post status:

```
register_post_status('my_custom_post_status', array(
    'label' => __('The Label', 'domain'),
    'public' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'show_in_admin_all_list' => false,
    'label_count' => //blablabla
));
```

The `show_in_admin_all_list = false` should hide the status in the all-list but it doesn't. Only if I set the public to false it is not visible. But I need `public = true`!

Any ideas

Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_status

Comment: `register_post_status` is **not!** meant to be used by themes or plugins. I wrote a pretty intense plugin to work around that fact, but anyway: It's not that simple and you will simply have to drop the idea of custom post status. Search through my answers to read more about it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean!? I've already incorperate custom stati in my plugin and have no problems. You have to many answers to look through. Any specific one?

Comment: You will have to search on your own, but to sum it up: The post status is hard coded in lots of cases in core and even when this works in _some_ cases, it will simply crash in others. Believe me: I digged a lot in core and you'll be surprised, where the post status is used. And you're missing lots of cases when just throwing and additional status in. Hint: The post status API is _not_ finalized since WP 3.0 - you can see this in the incomplete phpDocBlocks and read on wp-hackers about it.

Comment: Yes I found them missing in the quick edit section for instance and on some other places. I did some workaround in two or three cases so should not a big deal to "fix" this on later version

Comment: Do whatever you want, I already stated that you'll run into problems - incl. the fact that the API is already started and will be finished with some version. Prepare to hit the wall ;) ... and rebuild everything (incl. fixing everything in your DB) with a future version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This solves my problem:

```
register_post_status('my_custom_post_status', array(
    'label' => __('The Label', 'domain'),
    'public' => !is_admin(),
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'show_in_admin_all_list' => false,
    'label_count' => //blablabla
));
```

`!is_admin()` makes the status only public on the frontpage.

If you find a better solution please post it here!

Answer (score 0):

My approach, inspired by @revaxarts, is this:

```
if (is_admin() && $_GET['post_type'] == 'post') {
  $makepublic = true;
} else {
  $makepublic = false;
}

register_post_status( 'suspended', array(
      'label'                     => _x( 'suspended', 'Status General Name', 'myadvert' ),
      'public'                    => $makepublic,
      'exclude_from_search'       => true,
      'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
      'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
      'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Suspended <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Suspended <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
 ) );
```

Because I do not want it to see those post on the frontend while I am logged in as admin.

Comment: is_admin actually returns true or false based on if you are looking at an admin screen or not. It doesn't have anything to do with your user role.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the `public` parameter, because you want to have more control over your posts, you should also hook the `pre_get_posts` action to change the main query:

```
/**
 * Display all posts on edit.php
 * Bug fix: the 'show_in_admin_all_list' argument for the 'register_post_status' function is ignored when the argument 'public' is set to 'false'
 * @link https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24415
 */
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query) {
    global $pagenow;

    if (!is_admin() || $query->query['post_type'] != 'YOUR_CPT' || $pagenow != 'edit.php') {
        return;
    }

    if (!isset($_GET['post_status']) || empty($_GET['post_status']) || (isset($_GET['post_status']) && $_GET['post_status'] == 'all')) {
        $query->set( 'post_status', array('publish', 'draft', 'foo', 'bar'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using publish press plugin to create a custom post status i changed the all post status into public, using this

```
register_post_status(
  $status->slug,
  [
    'label'       => $status->name,
    'public'   => true,
    'exclude_from_search'       => true,
    'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
    'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
    '_builtin'    => false,
    'label_count' => _n_noop("{$status->name} <span class='count'>(%s)</span>","{$status->name} <span class='count'>(%s)</span>"),
  ]
);
```

all post shown at front end but **edit.php all post page not working** it not showing the all the post which is relevant to custom post type and it also affected the woocommerce